# Resize a list of images in Mathematica for use with ListAnimate

Tags: graphics, animation, wolfram-mathematica

Suppose we have a list of images, like the following:

```
imageList = Table[Plot[Sin[k*x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {k, 1, 4, .05}];
```

We can animate those images like so:

```
ListAnimate[imageList]
```

But now suppose we want the animation bigger.
We could stick an ImageSize option into the Plot command used to generate the images, but suppose we're not allowed to tamper with imageList.

We could manually resize each frame in the list animation.
That works, but how can we accomplish that less tediously?

Comment: The original version of this was not the right question.  My apologies to Janus and High Performance Mark who answered it before I fixed it.  And huge thanks to them for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key option is [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageSize.html). You can use it with the various plot commands, as well as with `Show` and `Export`. 
`ImageSize` can be given as `{<width>,<height>}` (where either can be `Automatic` to have the other set according to `AspectRatio`) or as `<width>` which is short for `{<width>, Automatic}`. In short, you can do stuff like

```
gfx = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 200]
Show[gfx, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 100}]
```

If you really want control of the graphics layout, you need to start playing around with `ImagePadding` and `PlotRangePadding` as well, but be prepared for gray hair if you go in this direction!

Edit: For your particular case with the graphics already generated in `imageList`, it all comes together like so

```
ListAnimate[Show[#, ImageSize->800]& /@ imageList]
```

Comment: ImageSize with Show is the key!  I'm going to rewrite this question now.  Sorry for the lousy first version.

Comment: All makes sense now -- couldn't figure out how you had missed ImageSize to begin with :). But yes, `Show` is often nice for reformating Graphics.

Comment: Thanks again, Janus. If you want to edit in the Show /@ imageList trick (see my answer) I'll mark this as the Accepted Answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit puzzled by your question.

```
    ListAnimate[Table[Plot[x^n, {x, -5, 5}, ImageSize -> {100 n, 75 n}], {n, 1, 5}]]
```

works fine for me, in as much as it draws the images with the specified sizes.  It's a bit of a mess in this example, I grant you.  The ListAnimate command also makes a panel with a frame big enough for the largest graphic in this case.

Post again if I've answered the wrong question for you, that's one of my specialities.

Comment: Now I'm also puzzled by my question!  I guess ImageSize works after all.  I'm getting images from a function that I don't want to tamper with but I now see that I can just do ListAnimate[Show[#,ImageSize->600]& /@ imageList].  I'll try to clean up the question and/or add that as an answer.  Thanks so much, Mark, for helping despite the lousy question!

Answer (score 0):

The following is one viable answer to the question as currently worded, with thanks to the initial answers by [High Performance Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44309/high-performance-mark) and [Janus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212538/janus):

```
ListAnimate[Show[#, ImageSize->800]& /@ imageList]
```